# CSS selector for next element?

Tags: html, css

Curious if I did miss something or it is really not possible select next `label` for the following html chunk:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="alice" id="name-alice">
</div>
<label for="name-alice">Alice</label>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="bob" id="name-bob">
</div>
<label for="name-bob">Bob</label>
```

I'd like to select label for checked input, something like

```
input:checked + label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The `+` CSS selector obviously does not work here. Any idea how to get work around this ?

**rationale:** *Generally it may be considered a "parent selector issue", but input & label elements are specific as being paired with `for` and `id` attributes and was unclear if there is some counterpart in CSS.*

Comment: Can your markup be changed. With current HTML, you can't select the `label` based on `input`.

Comment: also consider using jQuery if you're flexible with it.

Comment: @Harry Why not ? `for` attribute assigns `label` to `input` by its `id`

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore: I can't explain why CSS selectors work the way they have been designed to. We have to ask those who wrote the specs but in CSS there is currently no way to do what you want without changing the markup. And, I don't think the working of the `for` has anything to do with CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 3):

Move label inside div:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
  <input type="radio" name="name" value="bob" id="name-bob">
  <label for="name-bob">Bob</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not proper solution as only `input` need to be formatted by `col-md-1` class, not `label`.

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore that's the only solution available without resorting to JS. Simply put, CSS does not have parent selectors. If the formatting of the label is so important, couldn't you just assign a class to the label and counter the styles imposed by `.col-md-1`?